# For my outlook plugin manifest file. Why I can't put "IdentityAPI" in Requirements>Sets?

Tags: plugins, outlook

The default outlook plugin manifest file's requirements sections looks like:

```
<Requirements>
    <Sets>      
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1" />            
    </Sets>    
  </Requirements>
```

However, I try to add "IdentityApi" inside, which following the api document - https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync

It said I can add `<Set Name="IdentityAPI"/>`, but when I install the plugin, it gave error message:

> This app can't be installed. The Requirements element can only
>   include one Set element. The name of the Set element must be
>   'Mailbox'..

However, in the document, it also mentioned:

> Important: In Outlook, this API is not supported if the add-in is
>   loaded in an Outlook.com or Gmail mailbox

My plugin loaded into outlook.office.com which belongs to office365, so, I don't think it is matter.

Any ideas?